# How can I migrate clusters from a rancher to another one

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher, rke, rancher-rke

rancher

I have two ranchers, (rancher1, rancher2), I have some clusters in my rancher1, my objectif is to migrate all cluster from rancher1 to rancher2.
(rancher2 is deployed using ha rke, however rancher1 is deployed using docker)

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Are the clusters managed by Rancher or imported?

Answer (score 0):

simple. unjoin the downstream cluster from rancher-1 and then join it to rancher-2.

Comment: this may take time, because of many clusters, i need to pass by each nodes and join them to new rancher-2.
there's a way to make them point directly to the new rancher ?

Comment: you dont need to join each node. Just generate join command and you are taken to a page showing the cluster id and the manifest ( having cluster agent deployment ) file. copy the content and execute using kubectl apply on the downstream cluster. it would be joined to the rancher

Comment: so if I understand, I need to access to my new rancher, generate a join command, after this execute the manifest content into my different clusters to join my new rancher.
can i have the command to generate join command ? thanks

Comment: you can do from rancher ui using Cluster Management option

Comment: Will this work for Rancher-deployed / managed clusters,or just for imported clusters?

Answer (score -1):

This doc shows how to migrate from one Rancher to another:
https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/backups/migrating-rancher/

Comment: This is for migrating the entire Rancher, it does not cover moving some clusters from one Rancher to another (without wiping everything on the destination cluster) (My use case is getting a cluster from a separate Rancher into the main shared Rancher)